# java - jvm default timezone update after operating system timezone changes

Tags: java, jvm

I have a jvm running on a windows machine.It displays the current time (including time zone information) using TimeZone.getDefault().
I changed my operating system from Eastern Time (US & Canada) to Central Time (US & Canada) and the time zone the jvm displays does not change accordingly.
When I restart the jvm, the time zone of the jvm is updated.
Is there a way to get the most recent time zone info from the operating system without restarting the jvm?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java timezone change at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917225/java-timezone-change-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4):

As you highlighted by your test, system time zone changes are not taken into account by the JVM at runtime.

This is referenced as a bug and it is still open.

- [OpenJDK link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4216582).
- [Oracle link](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4216582)

Comment: That bug is marked as won't fix without explanation - any idea why?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko, the bug is 22 years old. Yep, they probably won't fix it. Maybe the idea of an event driven workaround has been implemented. I am outdated on the evolutions of Java anyway...